# Stripe Webhook constructEvent method is returning 400 error when pointed to ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, stripe-payments, cryptojs

I have developed my application in windows OS and integrated Stripe webhook with the help of ngrok. Everything was smooth and I was able to receive the events from webhook. but once I moved it to ec2 instance on AWS Cloud, it is throwing me an error.

Error: (In Stripe Dashboard Webhook Attempts Section)

> Webhook Error: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined

It is strange that have not changed any piece of code and it still works on windows.

Complete Error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject
. Received undefined
    at prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)
    at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:111:9)
    at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:147:10)
    at Object._computeSignature (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/stripe/lib/Webhooks.js:65:8)
    at Object.verifyHeader (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/stripe/lib/Webhooks.js:107:36)
    at Object.constructEvent (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/stripe/lib/Webhooks.js:12:20)
    at /home/psuser/middleware/routes/carts.js:210:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at /home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/psuser/middleware/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received undefined

// End point Code


router.post('/webhook', async (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
});

// In app.js 


app.use(express.json({
  // Because Stripe needs the raw body, we compute it but only when hitting the Stripe callback URL.
  verify: function (req, res, buf) {
    var url = req.originalUrl;
    if (url.endsWith('/webhook')) {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString()
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET` contains the correct webhook endpoint secret when this code runs (starts with `whsec_`)?  Don't share your webhook secret here though!

Answer (score 1):

You can install micro (npm install micro) which has its buffer method

```
const { buffer } = require('micro')
```

in order to create the required type for the request:

```
const reqBuffer = await buffer(req)
```

then you can do:

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(reqBuffer, sig, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET);
```

But I think your problem is simply an ENV variable missing in your EC2 server did you `export STRIPE_WEBHOOKS_SECRET=secret` in your server?

Comment: I literally have the same problem, I checked if the process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET by checking the .env file and making the server console.log it. And it started with whsec . But still after trying to trigger the webhook it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential issue I ran into is that every webhook endpoint has a unique webhook key in Stripe. So your local whsec_... is not gonna work when you deploy in vercel for example. You need to grab the unique key from endpoint setup and provide into the deployment env.